# How to find transformation matrix for converting one basis to another?

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $B = \{(1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)\}$  and $B' = \{(2,1,1), (1,2,1), (-1,1,1)\}$ be two ordered bases of R^3.  Using transformation matrix $T$ $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ which transforms $B$ into $B'$, find $T(x')$ where $x'= (2,3,1)$.

[image]

[image]
After solving for a,b,c
[image]
[image]

How do I found out the transformation matrix and in turn the representation for T(x')?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I had found out the transformation matrix. transpose([(1,0,1),(0,1,4/3),(0,0,0)])

Comment: If we have a linear transformation that takes basis to basis, then it should be invertible. But your matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Are you sure about invertibility, then I should check my calculation if some thing is wrong. And let's assume calculation is right, then how will I T(x')?

Comment: I think I am getting wrog and unable to find the matrix, can you tell me how to find it?

Comment: Can you show your work in finding $T$?

Comment: I have added in the descriptiom my work in finding T, please let me know if I did wrong and what is the correct way of finding it?

Comment: You would want to write $(x, y, z)$ in terms of $B$, not $B'$. Once you do this, you have to write elements of $B'$ in terms of elements of $B$ and then you will get your matrix. As I said earlier, a linear map that takes a basis to another basis must be invertible. So, none of its columns can be zero.

Comment: I have added last image in the description as per the solution in terms of B, however I am unable to get it back via transformation matrix. What's the exact relation between transformation matrix, B  and B'?

Answer (score 2):

## Canonic transformation matrix

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
It can be shown, merely by checking the images of $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$, that the matrix where the $i$th column is the $i$th vector of $\mathcal{B}$ is the transformation matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to the canonic basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely $\mathcal{B}_c$.
Let's refer to this matrix as $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}→\mathcal{B}_c}$.

## Arbitrary transformation matrix

Given 2 ordered basis, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$, consider the matrices $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}→\mathcal{B}_c}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c}$.
Then $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}→\mathcal{B}'}$ = $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}_c→\mathcal{B}'}$ $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}→\mathcal{B}_c}$, i.e., by first transforming from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B}_c$, and then from $\mathcal{B}_c$ to $\mathcal{B}'$.
But $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c}^{-1}$=$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}_c→\mathcal{B}'}$, as
$$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}_c→\mathcal{B}'}^{-1}\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}_c→\mathcal{B}'}=I=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c}\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}_c→\mathcal{B}'}$$

So we have then
$$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c}=\pmatrix{2&1&-1\\ 1&2&1\\1&1&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1}$$
The inverse, $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c}^{-1}$, is equal to

> $$\pmatrix{2&1&-1\\ 1&2&1\\1&1&1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{1/3&-2/3&1\\0&1&-1\\-1/3&-1/3&1}$$

We finally have

> $$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}'→\mathcal{B}_c} = \pmatrix{1/3&-2/3&1\\0&1&-1\\-1/3&-1/3&1}\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1}=\pmatrix{-1/3&4/3&1/3\\1&-1&0\\-2/3&2/3&2/3}$$

I posted the calculations as spoilers so that you can do them yourself in order to get used to this kind of exercises.
Another good thing to know is that in order to check whether you have correctly computed this matrix, i.e., without making any mistakes, is by checking the images of the vectors of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Can't it be found out using this relation B′ = T B and thus T = B' . inv(B) ? It is giving different results. I am confused.

Comment: You will have to be more specific. 

What is $T$, $B$ and $B'$? I can assume $T$ is the transformation matrix from basis $\mathcal{B}$ to basis $\mathcal{B}'$, and $B$ and $B'$ are the canonic transformation matrices. 

If so, $B'=T B$ would not be true. As by looking the right hand side of the equality, you would be first transforming from basis $\mathcal{B}$ to basis $\mathcal{B}_c$, the canonic base of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $T$ takes in elements from basis $\mathcal{B}$, not $\mathcal{B}_c$.

Otherwise, you need to be more specific on your enquiry.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, mark this as the best one so that we can close it.

Comment: Not satisfied yet.

Comment: Then you can try to clarify what you are not understanding well enough.